# golang exec.Command couldn't run C binaries

Tags: c, linux, go, executable, status

I executing a C executable using exec.Command and exec.Start(). My C executable is in the current directory and this is my code

```
cmd := exec.Command("./a.out")
// stdout,err := cmd.StderrPipe()
stderr,_ := cmd.StderrPipe()

err := cmd.Start()
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

log.Printf("Waiting for command to finish...")
s,err := ioutil.ReadAll(stderr)
log.Printf(string(s))
err = cmd.Wait()
log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
```

When i run this code, this is the output i get

```
2014/12/10 07:49:39 Waiting for command to finish...
2014/12/10 07:49:39 Command finished with error: exit status 11
```

My C hello world program is

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
printf("hello world");
}
```

The C code is compiled with gcc version 4.8.2 and executable is a.out.

The C executable a.out is a simple hello world program, i am getting the correct output, but i can't understand why exec.Wait() is exiting with status code 11 and not with 0.

The executable('a.out') is running normally when i run on a linux terminal without any faults or errors

Comment: Could you post the listing of the C "Hello world" program as well?

Comment: I posted my c hello world program in the question above

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer from github [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9237)

It is returning 11 because the output length is 11 and there is no return statement in my hello world program. So main returns from AX register when it ended.

Comment: Excellent. +1. I will delete my answer.